# Will it be possible to build Metro Style App with the actual VS2012 professional?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm on MS Dreamspark page. I can see that there is a **VS2012 Express for web** and **VS2012 Express for Windows 8**. However, for the The professional version, there's only one product called **VS2012 professional**. Will it be possible to build Metro Style App with the actual VS2012 professional when **windows 8** is out? I'm really confused.

Thanks for helping

Comment: VS2012 Professional contains all of the capabilities that VS2012 Express for web and VS2012 Express for Windows 8 contain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the Metro (Win Store) SDK for the VS Express and while installing the templates will be installed under your professional version of VS.

Comment: Surely the Metro templates are already contained in VS2012 Professional.

Comment: May be they are there, but to build a WinRT App you need a toolkit which comes with VS Express. However, when you install the toolkit, if VS Professional is present, the tools are installed under it, ignoring the install of VS Express.

Comment: @Max Terminov, to build a metro app, I still need to install the express version alongside the professional one?

Comment: No, the template is just called a Windows Store app, as Microsoft is no longer using the word "Metro".

Comment: No, you don't need to install the Express VS. Here is the link for the Windows Store Tools (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/br229512.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The "Metro" template has been renamed to "Windows Store" as "Metro" is no longer being used by Microsoft. It is in VS Professional.